# Spring: How do I inject ENUM in Spring configuration with generics?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a class like this :

```spring
public class CheckSetFilter<E extends Enum<E>> 
{
   public CheckSetFilter(CheckSetManager<E> pCheckSetManager, E pCheckSetId)
}
```

I have this enum :

```spring
public enum StubCheckId
{
   STUBCHECK1, STUBCHECK2
}
```

I try to create such an object with Spring :

```spring
<bean id="checkSetFilter" class="com.iba.icomp.core.checks.CheckSetFilter">
   <constructor-arg ref="checkSetManager"/>
   <constructor-arg value="STUBCHECK1"/>
</bean>
```

It complains, it cannot convert from String to Enum. I guess this is because of the generic. It cannot know the type of enum to create. I also tried to give it a type hint, but no luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All you really have to do is to add a `value` tag **inside** the `constructor-arg` tag.

```spring
<bean id="checkSetFilter" class="com.iba.icomp.core.checks.CheckSetFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="checkSetManager"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="your.package.StubCheckId">STUBCHECK1</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Total coincidence I swear :) FYI All `enum` classes extend the abstract class [`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), where `E` is the type of that `enum` implementation. So a type param `E extends Enum<E>` just means "some enum type".

Comment: @PaulBellora Please would you like to check my new answer and see if you like it :-) I updated with the same generics as in the question.