# How to define input parameter to spring quartz targetMethod?

Tags: java, spring

I have a method and I want to add a scheduler task. Problem is I have some input parameters and I need to call this method with this parameters. Is there any way?

here is my method;

```
public class RunMeTask {
   public void printMe(List<StudentType> myList) {
       System.out.println("test");
   }
}

public enum StudentType{
    SENIOR,
    GRADUATE
}
```

Bean definitions;

```
<bean id="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetObject" ref="runMeTask" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="printMe" />
</bean>

<bean id="runMeCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/10 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

**EDIT:** I have found that I can add a new property called arguments but I am getting ClassCastException as expected. I need to send List of StudentType instead of List of String.

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to dr.domain.StudentType

<property name="arguments">
     <list>
       <list>
         <value>SENIOR</value>
       </list>
     </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Where do you receive those parameters?

Comment: @cralfaro Parameters are constant. I mean runMeJob will always call printMe method with SENIOR.

Answer (score 0):

The "arguments" property is a list of arguments for a method invocation.
But your first argument is a list itself. So you need to have list of lists. Try

```
<property name="arguments">
     <list>
         <list>
             <value type="com.your.package...StudentType">SENIOR</value>
         </list>
     </list>
</property>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I still don't know how to call this method with enum.

Comment: @hellzone Just google it. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174277/spring-how-do-i-inject-enum-in-spring-configuration-with-generics , updated answer for you.

Another solution - don't use spring ;) XML configuration - is a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach

Define a List which will be loaded with values from your properties file.

```
public class RunMeTask {
    @Value("#{'${arguments}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> myList;

    @Schedule(...)
    public void printMe() {
        //here you can convert your String list to Enum. Not sure if you can directly load the enums in the list from the properties file
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

In your application.properties

```
arguments=SENIOR,JUNIOR
```

Update:

As you said you can not use properties file or String. Then you could have a look at this link, explain quite good how to do it.

[Quartz programmatically adding parameters](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example4.html)

Comment: I can not use String class. Its forbidden for me. And I can not use any properties file.

Comment: @hellzone have a look at the update, i added one link where explain how to do it, but this change your first class, now you will have to create a bean where programmatically you will define the cron trigger and you will be able to add all parameters you need. But wont use Scheduler annotation again